# Me sale el error Oops an error ocurred cuando intento iniciar sesion con instagram en mi aplicacion de xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth2, instagram-api

Actualmente quiero acceder con una sesión de instagram en mi aplicación de xamarin forms, obtener su token, imagen de perfil y algunos datos relevantes de su perfil para mi aplicación, con el código actual que tengo me muestra la ventana de login de instagram pero cuando me logueo me sale el mensaje "Oops an error ocurred" y no se que se pueda deber esta situación.

Codigo del metodo entrar:

```
  string clientId = "xxxxxxxxx";
            string redirectUri = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    clientId = ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookiOSClientId;
                    redirectUri = ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookiOSRedirectUrl;
                    break;

                case Device.Android:
                    clientId = ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookAndroidClientId;
                    redirectUri = ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookAndroidRedirectUrl;
                    break;
            }

           // account = store.FindAccountsForService(ConstantesSocialNet.AppName).FirstOrDefault();

            var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId,
                ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookScope,
                new Uri(ConstantesSocialNet.FacebookAuthorizeUrl),
                new Uri("https://api.instagram.com"),
                null);


          //  AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(authenticator);


                authenticator.Completed +=
    (s, ea) =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (ea.Account != null && ea.Account.Properties != null)
        {
            sb.Append("Token = ").AppendLine($"{ea.Account.Properties["access_token"]}");
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("Not authenticated ").AppendLine($"Account.Properties does not exist");
        }


        return;
    };
```

Clase ConstanteSocialNet:

public static string AppName = "AppDipo";

```
public static string FacebookAndroidClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx";

// These values do not need changing
public static string FacebookScope = "basic";
public static string FacebookAuthorizeUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/";
public static string FacebookAccessTokenUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
public static string FacebookUserInfoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token={accessToken}";


public static string FacebookAndroidRedirectUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
```